# Distinguish the first rows where a given column's value changes in a grouped result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, case

I want to create a select query in SQL Server where I group the rows by a column (BaseId) and also order them by Status, RTime and Version. I want to add a column "isFirst" that has the value 1 if the BaseId value is the first in the group, and 0 if it's not.

My sample table:

```
  Table name: Head
  Id    BaseId    Name       RTime       Status    Version
   2       2      abc     04-12 12:34      1          1
   3       3      xyz     04-12 13:10      9          1
   4       2      abc     04-13 14:25      0          2
   5       3      xyz     04-14 12:34      0          2
   6       3      xyz     04-14 13:10      9          3
   7       3      xyz     04-16 14:25      1          4
   8       2      abc     04-16 17:40      1          3
   9       9      sql     04-17 02:23      9          1
  10       9      sql     04-17 07:31      0          2
```

Expected result:

```
  isFirst   Id    BaseId    Name       RTime       Status    Version
     1      10       9      sql     04-17 07:31      0          2
     0       9       9      sql     04-17 02:23      9          1
     1       5       3      xyz     04-14 12:34      0          2
     0       7       3      xyz     04-16 14:25      1          4
     0       6       3      xyz     04-14 13:10      9          3
     0       3       3      xyz     04-12 13:10      9          1
     1       4       2      abc     04-13 14:25      0          2
     0       8       2      abc     04-16 17:40      1          3
     0       2       2      abc     04-12 12:34      1          1
```

My query now looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Head
ORDER BY BaseId desc, Status, RTime desc, Version desc
```

I think I should use `CASE` to create the isFirst column, but I've had no luck so far. Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and a `case` expression:

```
select
    case when row_number() over(
            partition by BaseId
            order by Status, RTime desc, Version desc
    ) = 1
        then 1
        else 0
    end isFirst,
    h.*
from head h
order by BaseId desc, Status, RTime desc, Version desc
```